# divide two integers [leetcode] shift error while using unsigned short

Tags: c

here's the description:

> Given two integers dividend and divisor, divide two integers without using multiplication, division and mod operator.
>   Return the quotient after dividing dividend by divisor.
>   The integer division should truncate toward zero.
>
> - Both dividend and divisor will be 32-bit signed integers.
> - The divisor will never be 0.
> - Assume we are dealing with an environment which could only store integers within the 32-bit signed integer range: [−2^31,  2^31 − 1]. For the purpose of this problem, assume that your function returns 2^31 − 1 when the division result overflows.

I write a solution but got `left shift of x by y places cannot be represented in type 'int'` from line `s22 = s2 << curr;` while I just use unsigned short. I don't know why?

```
int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    bool flag = false;
    if (divisor == 0 || (dividend == INT_MIN && divisor == -1)) {
        return INT_MAX;
    }
    unsigned short p1 = 0,  p2 = 0, s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
    if (divisor == INT_MIN) return 0;
    if (dividend == INT_MIN) {
        dividend = 0;
        flag = !flag;
        p1 = 0x8000;
        p2 = 0x0;
    }
    if(dividend < 0) {
        flag = !flag;
        dividend = ~dividend + 1;
    }
    if(dividend != 0) {
        p1 = dividend >> 16;
        p2 = dividend & 0xffff;
    }
    if(divisor < 0) {
        flag = !flag;
        divisor = ~divisor + 1;
    }
    s1 = divisor >> 16;
    s2 = divisor;
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned short curr = 31;
    while(curr > -1) {
        unsigned short p11 = p1 >> curr;
        unsigned short p22, s11, s22;
        s22 = s2 << curr;
        if (curr > 15) {
            p22 = p1 >> (curr - 16);
            s11 = s2 << (curr - 16);
        } else {
            p22 = p2 >> curr | (p1 << (16 - curr));
            s11 = (s1 << curr) | (s2 >> (16 - curr));
        }
        if (p11 > s1 || (p11 == s1 && p22 >= s2)) {
            ret = (ret<<1) | 0x01;
            if (p2 < s22) {
                int tmp = p2 | 0x10000;
                p2 = tmp - s22;
                p1 = p1 - 1 - s11;
            }
            else {
                p2 -= s22;
                p1 -= s11;
            }
        }
        else {
            ret = ret << 1;
        }
        curr--;
    }
    return flag ? ~ret + 1 : ret;
}
```

I avoid using any data type bigger than int.

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but `while(curr > -1)` will always be true because curr is unsigned.

Comment: @Flau hah yes, I changed curr data type while met that shift error. was trying to solve shift error.

Comment: I'm guessing that message coming from `ret = (ret<<1) | 0x01;` because ret is an int

Comment: @Flau `s22 = s2 << curr;` this line

Comment: @KamilCuk seems reasonable, I will try to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as KamilCuk mentioned, I don't know why he deleted the comment.

left shift signed int is undefined behavior. and shifting unsigned short more that 16 is also undefined, as unsigned short is 16 bits. So I have to dealing these edges.

Answer (score -1):

for this question we have alternate method. please go through

```
int dividend, divisor, quotient, reminder;

while(1)
{
    printf("Enter no:\n");
    scanf("%d %d",&dividend,&divisor);

    for(reminder = dividend, quotient = 0;divisor <= reminder;)
    {
        reminder = reminder - divisor;

        quotient = quotient + 1;         
    }

    printf("Quotien: %d Reminder: %d",quotient,reminder);
}
```

Comment: problem with this method is if you divide 2^15 by 1 it will have to loop 2^15 times.